# How to get items id in properties.AfterProperties elements?

Tags: development

I try this in ItemAdding, but it isn't work(Gives Null):
  public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);

```
       if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
       {
           SPList lstOtherList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];

           DateTime dzienStart = new DateTime();
           DateTime dzienStop = new DateTime();
           dzienStart = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStart"]).ToUniversalTime();

           dzienStop = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["DzienStop"]).ToUniversalTime();

           while(dzienStart<=dzienStop){


               if (dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() ==  "Saturday" || dzienStart.DayOfWeek.ToString() == "Sunday")
               {

                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   continue;
               }

               {              
                   SPListItem item = lstOtherList.Items.Add();
                   item["Kontrakt"] = properties.AfterProperties["Kontrakt1"];
                   item["Pracownik"] = properties.AfterProperties["Pracownik1"];
                   item["Dzien"] = dzienStart;
                   item["Procenty"] = properties.AfterProperties["Procenty"];
                   **item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Id"];**
                   dzienStart = dzienStart.AddDays(1.0);
                   item.Update();
               }
           }

       } 

   }
```

Comment: Im'mining about this code 'item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.AfterProperties["Id"];'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Alex's great list](http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/) of BeforeProperties/AfterProperties in Event Receivers you should not be able to get any properties in `ItemAdding`.

However you can get the item ID in `ItemAdded`, like this:

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
  var someList = properties.Web.Lists["SomeList"];
  var item = someList.Items.Add();
  item["SomeID"] = properties.ListItemId;
  item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work, it's only add One element, and in the last record, and I must add them to the all elements, in wchich I adding.
Here is screen of error Added items:
[image]

Here is all the code:

```
       public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {

       base.ItemAdded(properties);
       if (properties.List.Title == "Wpisy")
       {
           var someList = properties.Web.Lists["Szczegoly"];
           var item = someList.Items.Add();
           item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.ListItemId;
           item.Update();
       }
   }
```

It's almost the same like Yours. It's only added last element, and only ID