# ID column how is she caled

Tags: development

What is name of ID kolumn please help. I have a code:

```
item["ID z Czas Pracy Wpisy"] = properties.AfterProperties["GUID"];
```

And don't know what is it name.

Answer (score 0):

The [ID Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id.aspx) is called ID.

You can not change the ID of an item.
However if the ID you want to set is larger than the next ID in the list you can hack your way to the correct ID by creating and deleting items. Not very pretty.

Comment: I don't want to change. I want to make alterative columin another list to have all the Idis from list "Wpisy" and if I should I want to delete some record's from "Szczegoly", wchich korespond to deleting record wpisy.

Comment: Is this perhaps related to your earlier question, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49960/how-to-get-items-id-in-properties-afterproperties-elements/49978 ?

Comment: Yes but I want to DeleteCascade, but I can't manage with it. without buttom edit